# How to find async Image status in an Sync Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, asynchronous, callback, onload-event

I am loading the image in the JS and waiting for its status on its onload event.
I have JS file included with source in the HTML, and want to know the status of the image loaded initially using JS.

Example:

`<html>
   <head>
         <script>
             var imgStatus = false;
             var img = new Image();
             img.onload = function(){
                imgStatus = true;
             }
             img.src = "http://mydomains.com/someimage.jpg";
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>`

The code for js1.js is

`window.onload = function(){
    // check for imgStatus = true and then only do something
    // till then do nothing
}`

Do I need to constantly check the value of imgStatus using setInterval or is there any other better way of waiting till the status is known.

Comment: can't you move the "new Image()" code into js1.js?

Comment: Where / when do you set the `src`-attribute of img?

Comment: @PrabuRaja no thats not possible as per my requirement, coz in that case the JS file loading will take additional time and then i will have to trigger the image which will cause additional wait for the pixel. in current case my image will load async although image.onload wont trigger until JS is ready

Comment: @MartinErnst i get the source in the HTML script tag itself. I want the image to be ready by the time JS with source is loaded. Although image.onload will be triggered

Comment: The `window.onload` is fired *when the resource(document) and its dependent resources(files, images, ...) have finished loading.* So you can simply check `imgStatus` in the `window.onload`: if true image is there, if false it has not been found. In both cases the loading process has finished.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to fire an event when the imgStatus is true for example:

```
img.onload = function(){
 imgStatus = true;
 $(window).trigger("img/ready");
};

function doSomething(){
 alert("image is ready");
};

window.onload = function(){
 if (imgStatus)
  doSomething();
 else
  $(window).bind("img/ready", doSomething);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility (deprecated since jQuery 1.8) - http://api.jquery.com/load-event/